# Receive message from async TCP client

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, tcpclient

I'm creating an async TCP client using C# but I'm a bit stuck trying to receive messages from my TCP server. Seems that my `Receive` function is not being called, because when I send a message from my server to the client, it doesn't show in my textbox (I'm using the `WriteOnLog` function to do it). I'm able to send the messages just fine, I'm only having trouble receiving it. Do I need to call it inside a loop?

```
namespace Simple_TCP_Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Socket _client;
        public class StateObject
        { 
            public Socket workSocket = null;
            public const int BufferSize = 256;
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];  
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
        public String response = String.Empty;

        public void StartClient(IPAddress ipAddress, int portnum)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portnum);
                Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                    new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                _client = client;
                btn_send.Enabled = true;
                Send(client, "Hello Server!");
                Receive(client);
                WriteOnLog("Response received : " + response.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteOnLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                client.EndConnect(ar);

                WriteOnLog("Socket connected to " +
                    client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteOnLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        void Receive(Socket client)
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject state = new StateObject();
                state.workSocket = client;
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteOnLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = state.workSocket;
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                    {
                        string Response = state.sb.ToString();
                        WriteOnLog(Response);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteOnLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        void Send(Socket client, String data)
        {
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
        }

        void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
                WriteOnLog("Sent " + bytesSent + " bytes to server.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteOnLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btn_send.Enabled = false;
        }
        delegate void WriteOnLogCallback(string text);
        private void WriteOnLog(string text)
        {
            if (this.listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                WriteOnLogCallback d = new WriteOnLogCallback(WriteOnLog);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(text);
            }
        }    
        private void btn_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress;
            int portNum;
            if (IPAddress.TryParse(txt_ip.Text, out ipAddress) && int.TryParse(txt_port.Text, out portNum))
            {
                StartClient(ipAddress, portNum);
                if (_client.Connected)
                {
                    btn_connect.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Server's IP Address and Port",
             "Invalid Address or Port", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
            }
        }

        private void btn_disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _client.Close();
            btn_connect.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(_client.Connected)//(networkStream.CanWrite)
            {
                Send(_client, txt_msg.Text);
                WriteOnLog(txt_msg.Text);
                txt_msg.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to move `Receive(client)` to the bottom of your `ConnectCallback` method

Comment: Also at the end of `ReceiveCallback` you will need to call `Receive(client)` again. I still have a [similar project on Github](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/Chatprogramma35) with tcp server-client communication.

Comment: Why are you using the old-style of async instead of `await`/`async`? Using `await/async` is much, much _much_ simpler.

Comment: Hello @Pieterjan, thanks for you attention and quick response! I tried your suggestion but since 'client' is a local variable I changed to Receive(_cliente) which is global and receives the value of client. Unfortunately it didn't work, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: I think the code you need is all in [this file](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/Chatprogramma35/blob/master/Client/Form1.cs)

Comment: Unless you have substantial throughput requirements, eg, over 1000 client connections and multi-gigabit throughput,or you're doing this as a learning exercise, there is very little need to use SocketAsync calls these days.  You're much better off using Tasks to provide the asynchronous socket services.

Comment: The problem is when you need multiple clients connecting to your tcplistener, that (on the side of the server, where you start the TcpListener) you cannot `await networkStream.ReadAsync()`, because you probably wouldn't be able to accept more clients. So like [here](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/Chatprogramma35/blob/master/Server/Form1.cs#L72) you'd have to not await `newClient.ReadAsync()`. So you wouldn't be able to find out [how many bytes have been read from the stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Thank you @Pieterjan! I used your code and it worked like a charm! I still don't know what I was doing it wrong but I least now I have a solid code to use! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.